# Change server IP before SMTP connect

Tags: php, validation, email, smtp, ip

I am tried to validate an Email using SMTP PHP. Now it working fine. I want to change my server IP before connecting to SMTP. Now by default, it takes my primary IP to run but I  want to run in my secondary IP of the server. How to change the server IP using PHP?

Current code:

```
if ($this->sock = fsockopen($host, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, (float) $timeout)) {
    stream_set_timeout($this->sock, $this->max_read_time);
    break;
}
```

Comment: You mean your server has two IP addresses and you want to talk to the SMTP server using the connection of one of those specific IPs?

Comment: Exactly @ADyson

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/750832/making-php-use-specific-network-interface-ip

Comment: Sorry @ADyson that's not working

Comment: That's because it is for cURL specifically. I was actually wanting you to look at the other answer which says that basically it isn't possible.

Comment: Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66439458/how-to-connect-given-ip-with-smtp-server-in-php this is my exact doubt and added my code

Comment: It's the exact same question. The extra code you showed there isn't relevant to the issue. Don't ask the same question multiple times please